# How to Track Histroy when user Click any Tab or anything?

Tags: lightning-experience, configuration

example: user first time clicked on "Account Tab" later Clicked Contact Tab.. need to track what opended user?

Comment: My suggestion would be a lightning component added to the toolbar with the auto-load, and that is listening to the redirect events and stores those in the background

Comment: Tq.Any document  or link is thier

Comment: Try listening to the event `aura:locationChange` or purely in JS with what is mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930927/how-can-i-detect-an-address-bar-change-with-javascript

Comment: Event monitoring from Salesforce Shield is a paid option but still an option worth mentioning

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=salesforce_shield.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You could leverage the "Event Monitoring" feature. Event monitoring provides tracking for lots of types of events, including:

Logins

Logouts

URI (web clicks)

Lightning (web clicks, performance, and errors in Lightning Experience and Salesforce1)

Visualforce page loads

API calls

Apex executions

Report exports

All these events are stored in event log files. An event log file is generated when an event occurs in your organization and is available to view and download after 24 hours. The event types you can access and how long the files remain available depends on your edition.

Note:-

==================

This is an additional purchase. You would need to contact your Salesforce Account Executive to get this enabled in your org.

I hope the above solution answers your query.

Thanks.

Abhishek Mudireddy